# Safest Steps to turn on water heater that has been off for 5 years

Tags: water, heater, damage

My water heater has not been in use for 4.5 years.  The system was winterized in 3 years ago.  What are the steps for filling it and turning it back on to avoid damaging it.

Comment: @keshlam, what are you "tuning up" on a water heater?

Comment: Whups, sorry; crossed my wires an was thinking of boiler, since my hot water is an indirect-heated tank. Never Mind...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to open the water line only slightly and let it fill slowly so it won’t have a shock of pressure. I would open the lower drain and get rid if any gunk that may have developed, and check that your anode rod is still there and not corroded away (if it was drained the anode would not have continued to corrode).

Once it is flushed and fully pressurized, open the valve all the way, then close 1/2 turn to preserve the packing.

Comment: While it's empty might as well check or just go ahead and replace the T&P valve too.

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY, Agreed.  That was the only thing wrong with our water heater when moving into a house that wasn't used in a year or two.  Cheap and easy fix.